# Ecto how to filter a has many through realtionship

Tags: elixir, phoenix-framework, ecto

I am learning how to compose queries using Ecto. I would like to filter results from a has_many through relationship, with one call to the database via `Repo.all()` if that is possible.

I assumed I could do this by composing this query using existing queries. e.g.

```
def users(organization_id) do
  Repo.get(Organization, organization_id)
   |> Ecto.assoc(:users)
end

def bookings(%{organization_id: organization_id}) do
  Repo.get(Organization, organization_id)
    |> Ecto.assoc(:bookings)
end
```

and then, reuse one of the above:

```
def bookings(%{organization_id: organization_id, user_id: user_id}) do
  Repo.get(Organization, organization_id)
    |> Ecto.assoc(:bookings)
    |> where([u], u.user_id == ^user_id)
end
```

But this does does not filter results by a given user_id. How can it be done? What am I missing?

**Schema Info:**

- An Organization can have many Users.
- A User can have many Bookings.
- An Organization has many bookings through Users.

Answer (score 2):

You are after [`Ecto.Query.subquery/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.Query.html?#subquery/2). Also, `Repo.get/1` already executes the query against the database; in your case, you should build the query and only then execute it.

> An `Organization` can have many `Users`

That said, there is no such field as `user_id` in `organizations` table. To be able to filter by `users`, one needs to have `users` in the query.

I believe, somewhat along these lines would work (it’s impossible to tell precisely without seeing real schemas.)

```
  users = 
    from o in Organization,
    join: u in User,
    on: u.organization_id == o.id,
    where u.id == ^user_id

  query =
    from u in subquery(users),
      join: b in Booking,
      on: b.user_id == u.id

  Repo.all(query)
```

Optionally, instead one might use [`Ecto.assoc/2`](https://hexdocs.pm/ecto/Ecto.html?#assoc/2) for the latter:

```
users
|> Repo.all()
|> Ecto.assoc(:bookings)
|> Repo.all()
```